# Setting an array of StructuredBuffer in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, hlsl, compute-shader

I have a ComputeShader in my Unity project which would take as input and an arbitrary number of binary masks. Each one is stored as a ComputeBuffer, which results from a different ComputeShader Dispatch. How can I pass them all to my shader, without transfering them back to host first?

I initially thought I could simply create an array of computeShaders like so:

```
StructuredBuffer<float>[] inputBuffers;
```

But then it appears I can't really set them from Unity's C# libraries.

Another approach I have seen listed here and there would be to have a single flattened buffer, that is a buffer which size is mask_size * N. If the data was on host I could then use `buffer.SetData(data_i, i * mask_size, (i + 1) * mask_size)`. But that's where my problem lies: the data is not on host, it is on GPU. Is there any way I can avoid having to do a transfer back to host?

Thanks for your help.

EDIT: TLDR; How can I concatenate N ComputeBuffer into a single ComputeBuffer, using Unity, without moving the data back to host?

Comment: I didn't quite understand your question, but seem like the same question: https://computergraphics.stackexchange.com/questions/9676/sharing-memory-between-compute-shader-and-pixel-shader

Comment: Hi @shingo. This is not quite what I meant. What I want is essentially concatenate N ComputeBuffers into a single ComputeBuffer where N is decided at runtime, without going back to host.

Answer (score 0):

I am still not sure what the right way to do this is but a workaround is to use a kernel to do the concatenation.

```
StructuredBuffer<float> inputBuffer;
RWStructuredBuffer<float> outputBuffer;
int offset = 0;
int size = 256;

[numthreads(THREAD_GROUP_SIZE, 1, 1)]
void AppendBuffer(uint3 id : SV_DispatchThreadID)
{
    outputBuffer[id.x + size * offset] = inputBuffer[id.x];
}
```

and then call it in a loop from C#

```
void concatBuffers(ref ComputeBuffer[] buffers, out ComputeBuffer result) {
  result = new ComputeBuffer(buffer.Length * size, sizeof(float));

  var kernel = myShader.FindKernel("AppendBuffer");
  myShader.SetInt("size", 256);
  myShader.SetBuffer(kernel, "outputBuffer", result);
  
  for (int i = 0; i < buffers.Length; i++) {
    myShader.SetInt("offset", i);
    myShader.SetBuffer(kernel ,"inputBuffer", buffers[i]);
    myShader.Dispatch(kernel, 256 / THREAD_GROUP_SIZE, 1, 1);
  }
}
```

As a side note:
In many applications, if the order of elements does not matter, Append/ConsumeBuffers might be more appropriate for working with arbitrary numbers of elements. If the order does matter (like in my application) and the number of masks to concatenate in this way is indeed runtime dependant, one will most likely have issues later down the line because a for loop of variable length will inevitably be involved. But this is not possible in hlsl where the number of iterations must be compile-time constant. So this is not a good design.